# Customizing theorem environments, eqnarray, and equation

Tags: fonts, equations, numbering, theorems

I almost always use the following environments: `equation`, `eqnarray` and environments that are defined in the preamble with the command `\newtheorem` (i.e. `definition`, `theme`, `Theorema`, `proposition` etc ...) for my dissertation.

But I would like to customize these environments as follows:

1. having a unified numbering all these environments of the type
   X.Y.Z where x = "chapter number" y = "section number" z = "number of the subsection"
2. numbering stay to the left of the right environment and not the name I mentioned these environments. 
   Exemple:

> ****"X.Y.Z Theorem "  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> (X.Y.(Z+1)) equation = equation
>
> X.Y.(Z+2) Definition XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX****

1. do not lose the automatic spacing before or after the environments defined by the command `\newtheorem` (i.e. `definition`, `theme`, `Theorema`, `proposition` etc ...)
2. Did not lose the italic font environments defined by the command `\newtheorem` (i.e. `definition`, `theme`, `Theorema`, `proposition` etc ...)
3. What did not come in with the environment comflito `enumerate`.
4. That I could set the font in the preamble to these environments.

Comment: Please elaborate: (2) Does this specifically refer to equations? (3) Have something like `X.Y.Z.n Theorem` or keep the traditional `Theorem X.Y.Z.n`? (5) What does this mean?

Comment: I changed the wording of your first point a little, hope it reflects what you meant.  Also, you should [Avoid eqnarray!](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/)

Comment: Are you thinking to a numbering similar to Dieudonné's "Treatise on Analysis"?

Comment: @egreg, yes similar to Dieudonné's "Treatise on Analysis".  But not a list of paragraphs. The abientes must be specified.

Comment: @Werner, I edit may question. See exemple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get sequential numbers by defining the theorem-like environments sharing the `equation` counter; the number on the left of the theorem header can be obtained by `\swapnumbers` (package `amsthm`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\swapnumbers

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}[equation]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}[equation]{Definition}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Title}

\section{Title}

Some text.

\begin{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

Some text and an equation
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\begin{definition}
A definition.
\end{definition}

Some final text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, you should avoid `eqnarray` and use something from the `amsmath` package such as `align`; see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align) for details on how to get started.

The numbering convention you requested can be achieved by combining `\numberwithin` from the `amsmath` package (which hopefully you'll be loading now so that you can avoid `eqnarray`!) and `\swapnumbers` from the `amsthm` package.

[image]

You can customize the fonts for your theorem-like environments using the format specified in the `amsthm` package, as detailed in section 4.3 of the documentation

[image]

Here's a complete MWE for your reference- note that other theorem packages are available such as `ntheorem`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum} % sample text
\usepackage{amsthm} % for theorems
\usepackage{amsmath}% for mathematical environments

\swapnumbers
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\numberwithin{definition}{section}

\begin{document}

\chapter{}
\section{Section}
\begin{definition}
\lipsum[1]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Definitely *do not* use `eqnarray`.  Check the `amsmath` package.
2. As for theorems: you might want to check the `amsthm` package or the `ntheorem` package (also look here: http://ctan.org/keyword/theorems).

Comment: Do you mean amsmath?

Comment: @mbork. Thank1's. I'll look at these packages in your answer. But I would be grateful if he had somewhere ready commands. But for many exorcise "eqnarry"? I need my dissertation on the numbering of the equations remain to the left of the equation as the eqnarray.

Comment: @mbork. Thanks for your answer. Your link's been very helpful.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: thanks, obviously yes.  Corrected.